# Android MediaRecorder release() issue and Video capturing is not in portrait mode

Tags: java, android

I am facing some issue while developing Video capturing application.

1) When I start capturing the Video, the `surface view` comes in landscape mode. I tried a lot. But i failed. I also referred
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29   .. but no result

2) I am using `release()` method. but when we use that, after capturing application get closed. if I donot use this in memory card there is a video with no any capture and zero size.

Can any body explain why it is happening so?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In second case when app closes, do you get any errors in logcat?

Comment: No.. I did not get any error Log or Crash except this log


 `CameraHal: stopPreview
09-09 20:43:04.154  1157  5236 D CameraHal: stop preview thread
09-09 20:43:04.185  1157  5236 D CameraHal: stopPreview
09-09 20:43:04.185  1157  5236 D CameraHal: CameraHal release
09-09 20:43:04.185  1157  5236 D CameraHal: deinitPvOverlay()
09-09 20:43:04.232  1157  1256 D AudioHardwareMot: AudioStreamOutMot::setParameters() fm_attenuate=0;fm_mute=0`

Comment: MediaRecorder methods must be called in the proper order as shown by the state diagram http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Comment: I have done same thing as per above link. Recording happen and it is saved to gallery. but after a recording finished. this application get shut automatically without any crash.
this happen when I used `release()` . if I dont use `release()` then application donot shut but also recording does not happen.

Comment: @balbanshah u need to set display orientation of camera first then set the camera to the media recorder like camera.setdisplayorientation(90) and then set it to mediarecorder but as Peter suggested do it in proper manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same issue for thread create problem and i stop first thread and my activity is below....Problem is gone.......... ...

```
<activity android:name=".SensorTest"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

I spent hours on a similar problem. Anytime I released the MediaRecorder and then pressed the back button, the app would close and restart--onPause, onStop, onDestroy wouldn't fire in the Activity I was leaving, it would just be dead and then onCreate would fire in the Application.

After a lot of experimentation, I discovered the problem went away if I added

```
mediaRecorder = null;
```

immediately after calling mediaRecorder.release();

Answer (score 1):

This is only to try to answer point 1:

You probably miss the following attribute inside `<activity>` tag in the AndroidManifest.xml. See more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

If you don't declare this, your app will never be notified of any device rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer only the question 1. I've stuck with this problem before, too. I found that you can use the function [setOrientationHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOrientationHint%28int%29) (API 9). Call this function before you call MediaRecorder.prepare(). You can setup the orientation degree for your output video.

Hope it helps, good luck!